# TV show with a family stranded on an island with weird spider webs

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw this live-action show in France in the late 70s and it was in color.

It was a family (I believe two parents, one boy and one girl) that end up stranded on some island and they have to survive. It was a kid friendly show.

The one thing I remember is that every morning, everything outside would be covered in some kind of spider webs which were very sticky and would hurt to the touch, so they use sticks to remove them. No spiders to be seen though. This was the key distinction between this show and other survival stories I can think about.

The story starts from the arrival (forgot if it's a boat or plane crash) and progresses into them settling, exploring, etc.

I never saw the end of it so I don't know how the plot went.

Can anyone identify this show?

Comment: Animated? Live action? Did it seem dubbed?

Comment: It was live action tv show; it didn't look like most French TV shows from the era and France had, at the time, mostly American and German shows, besides French.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is episode 21 of the *[The Swiss Family Robinson](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068137/)* TV series, **"[The Intruder](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1444549/?ref_=ttep_ep21)"** (1976).

From IMDB:

> A meteorite lands close to the Robinsons's treehouse home and brings an alien substance that almost drives the family from their island.

To be clear, this is an episode of the [Canadian series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Family_Robinson_(1974_TV_series)) that first aired in 1974, not the [US series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Swiss_Family_Robinson_(1975_TV_series)) which first aired a year later.

From Wikipedia:

> *Swiss Family Robinson* is a 1974–1975 Canadian television drama series, based on Johann David Wyss' 1812 novel *The Swiss Family Robinson*.
>
> The series consisted of 26 30-minute episodes, and diverged somewhat from the original novel. Only one season was produced, due to the development of a *Swiss Family Robinson* series in 1975 by ABC in the United States. This situation precluded sales of the Canadian series to the lucrative American market. Reruns, however, continued to be syndicated in Canada for many years, with stations often scheduling the program as part of their Saturday morning line-up.

You can view the scene with the web-like substance around the 10:34 mark in the video below.